# Injectivity of the homomorphism induced by the two-sheeted cover from $S_3$ to $S_2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am aware of the proof that a covering transformation $f: X \to Y$ induces an injective homomorphism $f_*:\pi_1(X)\to \pi_1(Y)$.  Thus the two-sheeted cover $f:S_3 \to S_2$ (where $S_g$ denotes genus $g$ surface) should induce an injective homomorphism $f_*: \pi_1(S_3)\to \pi_1 (S_2)$. I find this counter-intuitive.  So, I would like to understand this homomorphism explicitly.  In fact, if you can construct any homomorphism from $\pi_1(S_3)$ to $\pi_1 (S_2)$, that would also do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention.  $S_g$ denotes genus $g$ surface.

Comment: If $a_1, \dots, a_g, b_1, \dots, b_g$ denote the generators (with relation $a_1b_1a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1} \dots a_g b_g a_g^{-1} b_g^{-1} = 1$), then how about we map $a_i \mapsto a_i$, $b_i \mapsto b_i$ if $i < g$ and $a_i \mapsto 1$, $b_i \mapsto 1$ if $i = g$?

Comment: This map is not injective, right?  Or am I missing something?  I am assuming that you have constructed the map from $\pi_1(S_3)$ to $\pi_1 (S_2)$.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't read the question properly.

Comment: @Divakaran I've fixed those typos (almost). Please have a look and let me know if you found some mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***An easy way to visualize this map is following***: think $S_3$ lying on  $\mathbb R^3$ with one hole on positive  $x$-axis one hole on the negative $x$-axis and the center of the center hole is the origin. Then think of an angle $\pi$ rotation of $xy$-plane with respect to $z$-axis. Then this map will induce a deck-transformation of order 2 on $S_3$. Then you can visualize the map $f_*$.

The explicit description of this map is :

$\pi_1(S_3)= \langle a_1,a_2,a_3,b_1,b_2,b_3| [a_1,b_1][a_2,b_2][a_3,b_3]=1\rangle$  and

$\pi_1(S_2)= \langle e_1,e_2,f_1,f_2|[e_1,f_1][e_2,f_2]=1 \rangle$.

Consider a map $f_*: \pi_1(S_3)\to \pi_1(S_2)$

$a_1\mapsto e_1;  b_1 \mapsto f_1; a_2\mapsto e_2 ; b_2\mapsto f_2^2 ;
a_3 \mapsto ge_1g^{-1}; b_3\mapsto gf_1g^{-1}  $ [$g$ is described in the picture]

Here $f_*$ is an well defined injective.[image]

Comment: Please let me know if there is any typo while writing down the explicit map.

Comment: Initially by mistake I wrote down the homology map.

Comment: Thanks Anubhav and sorry for the late response.  I was thinking along the same lines.  I was however finding it difficult to prove that $[a_1,b_1] [a_2,b_2] [a_3,b_3]$ goes to identity under this map.  Don’t we have to check that?

Comment: As far as I understand, you chose the element $g$ so that this happens.  I guess you even changed the choice once.  It would be really helpful if you can explain this choice,

Comment: @Divakaran here is a full computation

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Now things are fully clear.